# .Moodle Local plugin , menu item not getting added to Site Administration

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle. I have created a local plugin setmotd.

A new menu item is not getting added to Site Administration.

Using moodle 2.8.5

In lib.php i have placed function :

```
function local_setmotd_extends_settings_navigation($settingsnav, $context)
{
    global $CFG, $PAGE;

    /*
    // Only let users with the appropriate capability see this settings item.
    if( ! has_capability('local_plugin/setmotd:view', $context) )
    {
        return;
    }
    */

    if($settingnode = $settingsnav->find('root', navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING))
    {
        $setMotdMenuLbl = get_string('menutitle', 'local_setmotd');
        $setMotdUrl = new moodle_url('/local/setmotd/set_motd.php');
        $setMotdnode = navigation_node::create(
            $setMotdMenuLbl,
            $setMotdUrl,
            navigation_node::NODETYPE_LEAF);
        if ($PAGE->setMotdUrl->compare($setMotdUrl, URL_MATCH_BASE)) {
            $setMotdnode->make_active();
        }
        $settingnode->add_node($setMotdnode);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to add menu item.I checked in moodle/lib/navigationlib.php , class settings_navigation in method load_administration_settings, the following line :

```
$referencebranch = $this->add(get_string('administrationsite'), null, self::TYPE_SITE_ADMIN, null, 'root');
```

So, with "root", the navigation_node type **has to be** TYPE_SITE_ADMIN, not 
TYPE_SETTING.

In firefox firebug, I had earlier noticed in the ajax call for loading site administration menu, that the css class for "root" was named TYPE_SITE_ADMIN.

Note, that I am not yet able to make the new menu item active. So notice that, that part using $PAGE, is commented.

```
    function local_setmotd_extends_settings_navigation(settings_navigation $settingsnav, context $context)
{
    global $CFG, $PAGE;

    /*
    // Only let users with the appropriate capability see this settings item.
    if( ! has_capability('local/setmotd:view', $context) )
    {
        return;
    }
    */
    $settingnode = $settingsnav->find('root', navigation_node::TYPE_SITE_ADMIN);
    if( $settingnode )
    {
        $setMotdMenuLbl = get_string('menutitle', 'local_setmotd');
        $setMotdUrl = new moodle_url('/local/setmotd/set_motd.php');
        $setMotdnode = navigation_node::create(
            $setMotdMenuLbl,
            $setMotdUrl,
            navigation_node::NODETYPE_LEAF);
        /*
        if ($PAGE->$setMotdUrl->compare($setMotdUrl, URL_MATCH_BASE)) {
            $setMotdnode->make_active();
        }
        */
        $settingnode->add_node($setMotdnode);
    }
}
```